# Get Facebook user Events list and details in Android

Tags: facebook, events

```
new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/"+MainActivity.ME_FBUSER_ID+"/events",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
                    Log.e("event",response.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
).executeAsync();
```

returns

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set Permissions? That for you have to set `user_events` permission. At user login time. as like below

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_events", "friends_events"));
```

**See below link for user permission:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#adding

> You have to add permission after you can get it.

**If you have done all above things and not work then you have to put app for review.**

if you get  Debug Message as like blow image in Graph API Explorer. You have to put app for review.

[image]

> Documantation say `To use the user_events permission you need to submit your app for review.`

See below ScreenShot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your access token probably doesn't contain the `user_events` permission... Do you gather it during login?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_events

Comment: I have put the event reading permission i loginbutton permission

Comment: `user_events` requires Login Review. Did you pass that? Have you debugged your access token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken